# Appending bullet point sentences to main sentence using python

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I have a paragraph which is like in the following format,

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry;
(a) It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages; and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
(b) Contrary to popular belief; Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.

so for this I need to collect the bullet point (a) and (b) and append it to the main section like bellow,
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages; and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

and

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Contrary to popular belief; Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.

Note: ; can be :, :- and (a) can be (i) or any type of bullet point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your bullet points are always enclosed in brackets since you haven't stated otherwise. I am exploiting that.

Here is a possible solution:

```
import re
stri="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry; (a) It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages; and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. (b) Contrary to popular belief; Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text."
matches=re.findall("\A(.*?)(?:(?:; )|(?:: )|(?:\-))(\(.*\).*?(?:\(|\Z)){0,}",stri)
bullets=re.findall(".*?\)(.*?)(?:\(|\Z)",matches[0][1])
liststr=[]
for i in bullets:
    liststr.append(matches[0][0]+i)

print(liststr)
```

Output from this:

```
['Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages; and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. ', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Contrary to popular belief; Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.']
```